# Type-checking the dynamic value of an action creator parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

In my Redux structure, I have 2 action creators — `set` and `add`. The type of payload in `add` should be either a User object or a Post object while in `set` it should be either a `string` | `number` | `boolean` | a User object | a Post object | array of users | array of posts.

```
type Payload = string | number | boolean | User | Post | User[] | Post[];

interface SetItem {
    type: string;
    name: string;
    payload: Payload;
}

interface Add {
    type: string;
    name: string;
    payload: User | Post;
}

export const set = (name: string, payload: Payload): SetItem => ({
    type: 'SET',
    name,
    payload,
});

export const add = (name: string, payload: User | Post): Add => ({
    type: 'ADD',
    name,
    payload,
});
```

In my reducer, I combined the types of two in `Action` interface.

```
type Payload = string | number | boolean | User | Post | User[] | Post[];

interface Action {
    type: string;
    name: string;
    payload: Payload | (User | Post);
}

function reducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
    if (action.type === 'SET') {
        let property: Payload = state[action.name];

        property = action.payload;

        return state;
    }

    if (action.type === 'ADD') {
        const property: (User | Post)[] = state[action.name];
        const payload: User | Post = action.payload;

        property.push(payload);

        return state;
    }

    return state;
}
```

You would notice that inside the second `if` statement, I declared a `payload` variable and set its type to `User | Post` but the error is saying that:

> the type `Payload` is not assignable to the type `User | Post`.

Or maybe the way I type-check my initial state has something to do with the error.

```
interface State {
    [index: string]: User[] | Post[];
    users: User[];
    posts: Post[];
}

const state: State = {
    users: [],
    posts: [],
};
```

I need help in type-checking a payload value that has different types in different actions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform a type guard, since at this point `action.payload` COULD still be a `string | number | boolean | User[] | Post[]`. You could do this by defining two different Action types, which would be narrowed to one or the other by checking `action.type`:

```js
interface SetAction {
    type: 'SET';
    name: string;
    payload: Payload;
}

interface AddAction {
    type: 'ADD';
    name: string;
    payload: User | Post;
}

type Action = SetAction | AddAction;

function reducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
    if (action.type === 'SET') {
        // We DEFINITELY have a SetAction here
        let property: Payload = state[action.name];

        property = action.payload;

        return state;
    }

    if (action.type === 'ADD') {
        // We DEFINITELY have an AddAction here
        const property: (User | Post)[] = state[action.name];  // is this safe?
        const payload = action.payload;

        property.push(payload);

        return state;
    }

    return state;
}
```

**[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=25&pln=22&pc=28#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFARDAygUQEroDcUA9CVAFICucwUAZgPbIAmEAtowHa2ICGwAJbcAUKEhQACo1qoMkgPJYAKkVLlqspqw7deA4VxFjw0SXxAAbRnxZzegrgHMoAHyhcq7AEZI3Ub0ZGSwg+Ln94P3dpWXdIxABtAF1-GOBkwmNjR2Akej4AY2gsCGAAQQKhbigAbxEoBqhxCAAuKAByXGV2zMaPPnZWqAdnXsawC2tbNvMrGxZMgF9srlzEfKKoMpYWCqrwur7mtvaygBEznvrGrgGhkacxhom56dgEZGiZYCXjZq3KoY5CVyoDqu5trswVxMiJ6FQuNCoIgICwqEVEAAKWgCIZhEAAGighX2bT2hgAlG18bVrg1BPQoJiSYYAHT-FCcjpddoU2l9PohOhgRCMSCIUAzSbzezAXEJFncVm3QZJWEC8ai8WgOSKrisl5TBbGDUNFHAKiIcI43JPKDLOlQBlMvXs0yoLmnC68-mmgp6YVapCSpnxVLfCnJWXy10qiBqx19f08YXS2y66EGtPGxOasXBkAGmgAC0xhvmFPVpvNlutcttjodfRrVuG9YgSyAA)**

Comment: The error is still there. Also the type of `property` should be either an array of users or an array of posts because a returned item from http response will be added to either one of them depending on the data. So I think the type-checking I did to it is safe.

Comment: It isn't erroring on TypeScript Playground. Regarding `property`, that's a different question. You have to think about how you type your `State` object as well, if you want all these guarantees.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to erase `User | Post` on my payload variable. The error is still there though but it now says that the argument of type `Payload` is not assignable to parameter of type `User | Post`.

Comment: How are you defining your Action subtypes? Look closely at the SetAction and AddAction types in my answer.

Comment: Once you check action.type, typescript KNOWS if you have a SetAction or an AddAction. If each of those types have their payload property defined correctly, you KNOW what those are too. This is the basis of typeguards. Read the manual if you need a refresher.